# how to solve attempted to divide by zero in c#?

Tags: c#, textbox, decimal, division

I am getting this bug,
I wrote code like this below

code:

```
decimal Amnt;
decimal.TryParse(txtAmnt.Text, out Amnt);
int tnure=1;
int.TryParse(txtTnre.Text, out tnure);
txtDdctAmnt.Text = (Amnt /tnure).ToString("0.00");
```

when in textbox value 0 I am getting this error.If it is possible give answer to me.

Comment: What do you mean "solve"? Either validate value before division, or handle exception, if the validation isn't an option here. I hope, you don't looking for a way how to allow to divide by zero.

Comment: check 'tnure!=0' value before the division operation take place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about simply using an `if` to check before dividing by zero?

```
if(tnure != 0)
    txtDdctAmnt.Text = (Amnt / tnure).ToString("0.00");
else
    txtDdctAmnt.Text = "Invalid value";
```

Answer (score 3):

check if `tnure` is not 0,you are getting Divide by Zero Exception,more help at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173160.aspx

```
decimal Amnt;
        decimal.TryParse(txtAmnt.Text, out Amnt);
        int tnure=1;
        int.TryParse(txtTnre.Text, out tnure);
if(tnure!=0)
{
        txtDdctAmnt.Text = (Amnt /tnure).ToString("0.00");
}
else
{
/*handle condition*/
}
```

Comment: THANK U I TRIED IT IS GETTING CORRECT ANSWER

Answer (score 1):

When tnre is 0, `Amnt /tnure` is a division by 0.  You need to check whether tnre is 0 before dividing, and don't divide by tnre if it is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in try/Catch Statement like this

```
    try
    {
    decimal Amnt;
    decimal.TryParse(txtAmnt.Text, out Amnt);
    int tnure=1;
    int.TryParse(txtTnre.Text, out tnure);
    txtDdctAmnt.Text = (Amnt /tnure).ToString("0.00");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // handle exception here
        Response.Write("Could not divide any number by 0");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you wait to the exception? can't you check tnure? and never catch the global `Exception` exception.